# connect with oracle database through visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle11g, odac

I have installed oracle database 11gR2 and visual studio 2010 32 bit. Then I tried to install odac for oracle client 11.2.0.1.2. It gives this error.

"Oracle Data Access Components for oracle client 11.2.0.1.1 can only be installed over and existing Oracle client 11.2 Hoeme. Use Oracle Data Access Components for Oracle server 11.2.0.1.0 to install in Oracle server 11.2.0.1.0 Home."

I can't understand what to do next.Hope your helps...
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you install, choose a new Oracle Home directory with the client. If you want a step by step guide how to do this, follow this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18751/installation.htm#CACBIDHI